# Sending a hex command to Device using Php and COMPort (USB to RS232)

Tags: php, serial-port

HI I have posted a lot of question regarding this but it is different from this one. It's like a continuation or rather other part question.

I have a card vending device (CVD), Now my laptop has no serial port so I used the USB to connect to the device.

My cable is, USB to RS232. Now I have downloaded or rather given to me by a friend an exe which send a command to device on a click of a button. But note that this is an exe only. No Source code.

I'm now creating my own program to send the data command to device on a button click as well.

Here's some facts:
**1. Im using Php**
**2. I'm need to send a hex command of 42**
**3. is the command for cardout**

Here's what I've got so far.

```
exec("mode COM15 BAUD=9600 PARITY=none data=8 stop=1 xon=off");

      $fp = @fopen('COM2', "w+");

      if (!$fp) {
          echo "Not open";
      } else {
          sleep(3);
          echo "Open";

          $str = "01";
       $str = pack("H*",$str);

          fwrite($fp, $str);
          fputs($fp, $str);

       $str2 = "2A";
       $str2 = pack("H*",$str2);

          fwrite($fp, $str2);
          fputs($fp,$str2);

          $buff = fread($fp, 10);
          echo ">> ".$buff." <<";
          //fclose($fp);
      }
```

But it is just returning **Open>> <<**

Answer (score 0):

Try with a 
    print_r($buff);
It will show you the type of variable and all data it contains and maybe continue working on how to show that variable.